# terminal is running wrong .py file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a file in python called OOP.py and for some reason, terminal keeps running another file I have called exp29.py

I have changed the name of OOP.py file, and have deleted exp29.py, but still terminal is calling the exp29.py file when I hit enter on python OOP.py

At the bottom is the code in the OOP.py file. Annoyingly I've already deleted the exp29.py file, but I'm new to python and it was me trying out %+letter combinations in strings.

stuff like

num = 4

print "I would like %d" % num

I did this running through %d • %i • %o • %u • %x • %X • %e • %E • %f • %F • %g • %G
• %c • %r • %s • %%

Does anyone know why this is happening? TIA.

OOP.py code

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys


WORD_URL= "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"

WORDS= []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
        "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object): \n\tdef__init__(self, ***)":
        "class %%% has-a- __init__ that takes self and *** parameters",
    "class %%%(object): \n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
        "class has a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters",
    "*** = %%%()":
        "Set *** to an instance of class %%%",
    "***.***(@@@)":
        "From *** get the *** function and call it with parameter @@@",
    "***.*** = '***'":
        "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
        }
    

PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

for words in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())
    

def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                    random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []
    
    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1, 3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))
        
        for sentence in snippet, phrase:
            result = sentence[:]
        
        #fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)
            
        #fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = results.replace("***", word, 1)
            
        #fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)
            
        results.appent(result)
        
    return results

try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)
        
        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snipper, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question
                
            print question
            
            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER: %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you starting the script?

Comment: Add a snapshot of your terminal for us to assist you further

Comment: I apologize for what might be a silly question, but did you save your changes to OOP.py before you ran it? Are you sure you are saving it to the same file, that is to say, in the same folder/directory, as the one you're running?

Comment: Also, why are you using Python 2? It is no longer supported, so you should be using 3.

Comment: @matszwecja starting the script with python OOP.py ENTER

Comment: @jazz i'm not allowed to add pics yet apparently cos I'm too new to stackoverflow. But it is running the exact ex29.py programme as if I was typing python exp29.py ENTER into terminal

Comment: @DanGetz OOP was a brand new file, but thanks for checking, this sounds llike something i would do.

Comment: @ndc85430 I'm learning from a book everyone seems to love (lean python the hard way) that insists I ignore v3 for the time being.

Comment: @Mike Well, it was published in 2013. Python 2 is completely deprecated since 2020, but has been discouraged many years before.

Comment: @Mike What do you get when you do "type OOP.py" in the same terminal? Also, +1 for dumping Python 2. There's no good reason to bother with it when learning on your own.

Comment: What are the contents of your cwd? Do you by any chance have file called "random.py" there?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman much like now, I was just going with what some rando on the internet suggested. If v2 is completely obsolete then I'll stop today and move onto v3. This is my first ever attempt learning to code so all v new to me.

Comment: @matszwecja -bash: type: OOP.py: not found 
For cwd: no random.py in there.

Comment: @Mike I forgot it's not Windows, `cat OOP.py` instead of `type...`

Comment: It's probably as matszwecja suggests. You have a python file called `random.py` which is imported and run when you do `import random`. That random file might in turn import and run `exp29.py`.

Comment: @matszwecja it prints (but does not run)the code in terminal

Comment: ah, I found random.py! Thank you all very much for your help!